# Git package using mvn and npm

Tags: git, maven, npm

We have couple of git in which some are maven projects and others are npm project. We have a bunch of shell and python scripts in each which perform some additional build actions. I have noticed that it is basically the same script being used over and over again. I would like to be able create a new git package with these build scripts  which both of these would depend on so that I can share these common scripts rather than copying and pasting it. However I'm not sure what type of package should it be since they use different systems for managing the dependencies. I am familiar with npm and haven't used maven much but what is the best approach to make this common package both a maven project and npm so that the both types of consumer package can depend and use it?

Answer (score 0):

the company i work for has ~10 git repositories written in c/c++, java, python, and javascript.

what we did was install a single repository server able to speak all the required protocols (in our case rpm, maven npm and grunt). even without one you could publish your common script package as a *.zip to some maven repository and pull it from other projects. for maven you can use the [dependency plugin to extract the dependency](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html), while anything else can just pull the *.zip from the maven repo using http. npm supports [URLs as dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#urls-as-dependencies)